# Assigning the value of a character pointer into a character array

Tags: c, arrays

I am using the `strtok` function in C. My goal is to divide the string into smaller tokens then assign those individual tokens to character arrays or strings. Here's my code:

```
int main(void)
{
   char whole[100] = "Please help me";
   char *token;
   char individual[100];

   token = strtok(whole, " ");
   individual = token;   //I don't know what code fits in here
}
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: What is the output you are getting?

Comment: Is google down again?

Comment: Your question as stated doesn't make sense. You can't simply assign `token` to `individual`. You'll need to use `strcmp`.

Comment: Take a look at [strdup()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) or [strcpy()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/)

Comment: @b4hand I'm pretty sure that was exactly his question.  I don't think he understands pointers in C.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char whole[100] = "Please help me";
    char *token;
    char *individual[50];
    int i=0, n;

    token = strtok(whole, " ");
    while(token != NULL){
        individual[i++] = token;//just store pointer or make clone = strdup(token);
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    n = i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        puts(individual[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
char whole[100] = "Please help me";
char *token;
char individual[50][100];
int i=0, n;

token = strtok(whole, " ");
while(token != NULL){
    strcpy(individual[i++], token);//copy to char array
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
n = i;
for(i = 0; i < n; ++i){
    puts(individual[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

regarding calls to strtok()

Always check (!= NULL) the returned value to assure the operation is successful..

regarding the line: 'individual = token;'

This just assigns a pointer.

Suggest using:

```
strncpy( individual, token, sizeof( individual)-1 );
```

HOWEVER, 'Please help me" is a string literal. string literals are in readonly memory. so calling strtok() (which tries to replace a char with a '\0' will cause a seg fault event.

Suggest:

```
char whole[] = strdup("Please help me: );
....
free(whole);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why he would want to use `strncpy` vs `strcpy`?

Comment: I started to suggest strcpy(), however strcpy() can cause lots of problems if not used correctly.  Much safer to use strncpy() as that limits the number of characters copied.   The question reads like a student.  I think it is best to point students in the safest direction, They can 'branch out' when they are comfortable with the C language.

Comment: Fair enough :) Was really just curious.

Comment: ahhhh (egg on face) I now see that the literal is being assigned to an array, so worries about readonly memory, etc are mute *sigh*  That's what happens when I start typing before fully thinking the problem thorugh

Comment: `char whole[] = strdup("Please help me: );` is wrong. Either make `whole` a pointer or remove the `strdup` and the `free` and directly assign the string.

Comment: You are incorrect about `whole` being immutable and needing to use `strdup` in this context. String literals are normally read-only, but since this is a direct array initialization, it is defined as a shorthand equivalent for `char whole = {'P', 'l', 'e', ..., '\0'};` which is a mutable array.